# Test Component Router Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to test my component which is wrapped in a Link component of `react-router-dom` that looks like this:

```js
// PokemonItem/index.js

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const PokemonItem = ({ pokemon }) => {
  const {
    id, img, name, number, types,
  } = pokemon;
  return (
    <Link to={{
      pathname: `/pokemon-details/${id}`,
      state: { pokemon },
    }}
    >
      <div className="pokemon-card">
        <header className="card-header">
          <img src={img} alt={name} />
        </header>
        <main className="card-body">
          <h6>
            #
            {number}
          </h6>
          <h2>{name}</h2>
        </main>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default PokemonItem;
```

I used the example of react testing library to create my test file:

[https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router](http://react-testing-library)

And this is my test file:

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'
import React from 'react'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'

import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

import PokemonItem from '../components/PokemonItem';

test('full app rendering/navigating', () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  const pokemonItem = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bulbasaur',
    number: '#001',
    img: '',
    types: [],
    height: 10
  };

  render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <PokemonItem pokemon={pokemonItem} />
    </Router>
  );

  expect(screen.getByText(/bulbasaur/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

  const leftClick = { button: 0 };
  userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/bulbasaur/i), leftClick);

  expect(screen.getByText(/height/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

The click event should redirect to a component containing just the text "height", which is my PokemonDetails page, but without success.

This is the error displayed on the console:

```
Unable to find an element with the text: /height/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    <body>
      <div>
        <a
          href="/pokemon-details/1"
        >
          <div
            class="pokemon-card"
          >
            <header
              class="card-header"
            >
              <img
                alt="Bulbasaur"
                src=""
              />
            </header>
            <main
              class="card-body"
            >
              <h6>
                #
                #001
              </h6>
              <h2>
                Bulbasaur
              </h2>
            </main>
            <footer
              class="card-footer"
            />
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </body>

      62 | 
      63 |   // check that the content changed to the new page
    > 64 |   expect(screen.getByText(/height/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
         |                 ^
      65 | })
```

It's not being redirected to the details page.

I've tried with a lot of tutorials, and different ways to simulate the click including the fireEvent.click method without success. What more do I need to do?

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing while navigating?

Comment: I added the exact error description in the question, the page is not being redirected to the details page

Comment: Maybe you should pass a string value inside `screen.getByText()`

Comment: I also tried that, but the first assertion is confirming that the title is present, and the error is confirming that the click is not working. I also tried to move the Link as the example but nothing worked

Comment: You don't render any routes in your `Router` wrapper so why or how could the link push a new route that is testable? This doesn't appear to be an appropriate unit test for your `PokemonItem` component, but rather a test case for your routing component.